# Which one is considered the canonical jQuery plug-in for table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a plug-in to present a table of data in a HTML page. Data is coming from Ajax as XML or JSON. Requirements are fairly standard:

1. Plug is supported, with a live community
2. Table binds to data, or a mechanism to fill table with data.
3. Columns are sortable with the standard UI
4. Support for filters
5. Support for search (assisted search)
6. Preferably, table looks good by default without any change. Able to customize
         every aspect of the table
7. Support interaction. e.g. Mouse Hover or Click
8. Customizable.
9. Paging
10. Scroll bars

Overall I think these are very basic requirements. This question also fold another question: how do you choose a plug-in? Looking at the jQuery plugin page, shows there are 19 pages of plugins, with names such as "Yet another table plug-in".

I don't a "Yet Another ...". I'm looking for the canonical plug-in. The one that "everyone is using", which has live community, people to consult with, reasonable documentation (mainly examples), and bug fixes.

Googl'ing for 'jquery table plug-in' yields 70,000 articles, but I cannot identify any plug-in has multiple references.

Please also advise about a general strategy how do you pick a plug-in. Which web site to you go? Which blogs do you follow? etc. Down the road I'll have to choose a charting plugin (although there, there seems to be two main plug-ins that stands up: Flot and jQuery Google chart).

Comment: Thank you @Brian Tompsett for the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that there is an ultimate strategy to find exactly the plugin you need.
At least not without trying different options. Usually i limit the selection by what a see and read about a plugin (looking at exactly the things you mention: is there a good documentation? are there demos? is it still supported?), but in the end there's no way around trying out.

That said there are two plugins i used, which both do a very decent job, though i never used them for processing json-responses, only for making existing tables more dynamic and user-friendly. But both should do what you want.

- http://www.datatables.net/usage/server-side
- http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html

Lately i prefer *datatables* as i find the plugin easier to configure and better looking by default. (And as i use jquery-ui already i really appreciate the support for [themeroller](http://www.datatables.net/styling/)).

But i guess in the end the choice is pretty subjective.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you [jqGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). It meets all of your requirements.